# Json.Net Compact Framework deserialize performance

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization, json.net

I am testing the latest build of [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) and I am serializing a collection on the server and passing the string over using a WCF proxy.

The server call takes less than a second to return the data but on the PDA client side the deserialization `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of IList(Of BusinessUnitModel))(results)` is taking 20-30 seconds.

Is this performance usual with Json.Net or am I doing something wrong with the object or the serialization/deserialization?

I have tried downgrading to a 3.5x version of Json.Net and using the appropriate version on the server and the Compact version on the client but the performance is again poor.

**Shared Model**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Namespace Models

    Public Class BusinessUnitModel
        <Required>
        Public Property ID As Int32
        <Required>
        <StringLength(50)>
        Public Property Name As String
        <Required>
        Public Property IsInternalSupplier As Boolean
    End Class

End Namespace
```

**Server side serialization**

```
Imports Qsmart.DataProvider.Contracts
Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Namespace Serialiser

    <Export(GetType(IModelSerialiser))>
    Public Class JSonSerialiser
        Implements IModelSerialiser

        <Import(GetType(ILoggerHelper))>
        Private Property ExHelper As ILoggerHelper

        Friend Function Deserailse(Of TModel)(serialised As String) As TModel Implements IModelSerialiser.Deserailse

            If serialised Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("serialised")

            Try
                Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialised)
            Catch ex As JsonSerializationException
                ExHelper.Process(ex)
                Throw New ApplicationException("Could Not Deserialse The Model", ex)
            End Try

        End Function

        Friend Function Serailse(Of TModel)(model As TModel) As String Implements IModelSerialiser.Serailse

            If model Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("model")

            Try
                Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model)
            Catch ex As JsonSerializationException
                ExHelper.Process(ex)
                Throw New ApplicationException("Could Not Serialse The Model", ex)
            End Try

        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**Server Side Test Data Creation**

```
Public Function QSmartBusinessUnits() As String Implements IQSmartDataProvider.QSmartBusinessUnits

    Dim serialsedResult As String = String.Empty

    Try
        Dim tester As New List(Of BusinessUnitModel)
        tester.Add(New BusinessUnitModel With {.ID = 1, .Name = "Test1", .IsInternalSupplier = True})
        tester.Add(New BusinessUnitModel With {.ID = 2, .Name = "Test2", .IsInternalSupplier = True})
        tester.Add(New BusinessUnitModel With {.ID = 3, .Name = "Test3", .IsInternalSupplier = True})
        tester.Add(New BusinessUnitModel With {.ID = 4, .Name = "Test4", .IsInternalSupplier = True})
        tester.Add(New BusinessUnitModel With {.ID = 5, .Name = "Test5", .IsInternalSupplier = True})
        tester.Add(New BusinessUnitModel With {.ID = 6, .Name = "Test6", .IsInternalSupplier = True})

        serialsedResult = Serialiser.Serailse(tester)

    Catch ex As Exception
        ExHelper.Process(ex)
    End Try

    Return serialsedResult

End Function
```

**Compact Framework Deserialise**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim results As String = _proxy.QSmartBusinessUnits()
        Dim deserialise = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of IList(Of BusinessUnitModel))(results)
        BusinessUnitModelBindingSource.DataSource = deserialise
    Catch ex As Exception
        Stop
    End Try

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

If I remove the DataAnnotations from the model the performance is much better, it drops to around 2 seconds... Any idea why this is the case?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

    Namespace Models

        Public Class BusinessUnitModel
            Public Property ID As Int32
            Public Property Name As String
            Public Property IsInternalSupplier As Boolean
        End Class

    End Namespace
```

Comment: I would not be hugely surprised by that result, based on my own experiences serializing on weaker runtimes. Since meta-programming is restricted, the options are: reflection (slow), compile-time code-gen (hugely awkward to work with), or build-time emit (hard to do). Ultimately, the serializer has to work with what it has available, which isn't a lot for CF. If you have any option to change the serialization format, then other options may be available; for example, protobuf-net supports build-time emit targeting CF (meaning: you end up with a pre-built serialization dll for CF, specific to ...

Comment: ...your types). But: it isn't JSON.

Comment: @MarcGravell Wow! I didn't knew protobuf-net, but it seems to be what I was looking for some time.

Comment: You could try JSON#, a performance-scentric .NET JSON serialisation library: http://insidethecpu.com/2014/10/22/ultrafast-json-parsing/

Comment: @PaulMooney JSON# does not seem to be for Compact Framework.

Comment: @Jerther JSON# targets .NET 3.5, and can be easily ported to the Compact Framework by simply specifying the framework in the project properties. I can create a specific branch for this, if necessary.